# How do hackers compromise the defence network of a country?

Tags: exploit, attacks, vulnerability

Theoretically speaking, what is the process involved in hacking into a country's defence network? How does the hacker connect to the network in the first place? Are special  methods of hacking used in these kind of hacks?

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/64/4c/af644c995e5f39f90b63a61d49e04fb4.jpg

Comment: This question is way too broad. There are endless ways to someone to hack a network.

Comment: Absent more clarification (such as how did hackers compromise the Iranian nuclear network? or how did hackers compromise the US DoD?), this question stands a pretty good chance of being closed as "too broad".

Comment: It depends _heavily_ on the particular country. There are some countries where it is _easy_ to break into because e.g. their networking gear uses default remote administration passwords. Others have very tight security policies and require more lateral movement.

Answer (score 2):

You would do this the same way you hack into any other network. You figure out the domain names, IP addresses, host names etc.. and then perform reconnaissance and look for prospective weaknesses to exploit.

Comment: The same thing we do EVERY night, Pinky!

Comment: Try to not end up in a CIA black site? No, Pinky... wait ok yes.